# Is Firebase using cryptography?

Tags: cryptography, app-store-connect, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, xcode8

I am using firebase and email sign in method on my iOS app and also using database firebase, should I say "YES" on Export Compliance question about cryptography on iTunes Connect? if I should say yes what should I provide on the next step?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similar question - [IOS App submission Export Compliance: Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48086289/ios-app-submission-export-compliance-firebase). Based on the answers there it seems, that there is no need to answer "YES". But, as it was mentioned there - it is not a legal advice.