# IOS App submission Export Compliance: Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase

I am ready to submit my app to the app store, and after doing some research I still can't seem to find any information with regard to firebase in my app.

Is Firebase exempt? all I use it for is analytics and Admob.

so does Firebase utilize encryption and if it does do I have to worry about its export compliance or does Google have it covered?

I will consult a lawyer tomorrow but I am just curious as to what other people have done.

Comment: Did you get any useful information from the lawyer? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @kmell96 no, I temporarily removed Firebase, but I have until next year to file, so ill figure it out by then.

Comment: @Jurgen Could you give an update as of today? Facing the same decision.

Answer (score 1):

My app uses Firebase. If Firebase was exempt then I would have to add `<key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key><false/>` to my `Info.plist`, which I haven't. My app interacts with things like Firebase Storage, Firebase Database and opens links in Safari. I have been testing it through TestFlight with external users, which requires a beta review, and it passed. So I'm pretty you don't have to worry about it, but I'm not 100% sure.

**Update 1**

I found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40235468/how-to-pick-export-compliance-in-my-app) to a similar question. It says:

> If the only use is an https connection to facebook I would answer no. At WWDC16 I specifically asked this question twice of the security team and was told that they did not consider HTTPS to be encryption for this question.
>
> More:
>
> New U.S. legislation went into effect on September 20th. The new regulation removes the requirement to register your app simply because it uses encryption.
>
> Some links to the 9/20 changes: Changes to BIS's information security controls bring relaxed controls, removal of registration requirement Dentons, US Implements Regulation Changes for Encryption Products, Software and Technology Shadden, Export Administration Regulation (EAR) BIS.
>
> Note that other countries also have regulations covering sale of encryption including France.
>
> How this affects answering the Apple question is unclear. It my app useed encryption directly (my API calls directly to AES for example) I would answer "yes" and supply the above information.
>
> Disclaimer: This is not legal advice.

Comment: I have read that apple doesn't usually reject apps based on this. But I am more so worried about the legal implications associated with it.

Comment: as per edit: This works out for US and Canada as your exempt if the app is only available in this jurisdiction but its unclear for world wide export.

Comment: @eirikvaa what did you do after you uploaded officially to AppStore?

Comment: @LuisQuiroga This was a long time ago, so I don't remember exactly what I did after I uploaded to App Store, but I know I didn't have issues with this.